# Set multiple selected items in ttk Treeview

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

When using the Ttk Treeview control, I am getting a TclError when trying to programmatically set multiple selected items.

What is the correct way to set multiple items as selected in a Treeview control?

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Treeview.selection_set) isn't clear about what types are allowed for `items`:

> **`selection_set(items)`** *items* becomes the new selection.

I've simplified my code to the following:

```
try:  # python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
except ImportError:  # python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
for text in ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut']:
    tree.insert('', 'end', text=text)
all_items = list(tree.get_children())

print("all_items = {!r}".format(all_items))
tree.selection_set(all_items)
```

However, it raises an exception:

```
all_items = ['I001', 'I002', 'I003']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...
    tree.selection_set(all_items)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 1402, in selection_set
    self.selection("set", items)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 1397, in selection
    return self.tk.call(self._w, "selection", selop, items)
_tkinter.TclError: Item ['I001', not found
```

The last line of the error message makes it seem like it is converting the list of items to a string just using str, but the format isn't what is expected by the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `items` argument to `selection_set` cannot be a list. It must be either a space-separated list of iids or a tuple of iids.

Either of the following worked for me:

```
tree.selection_set(tuple(all_items))
```

Or:

```
tree.selection_set(" ".join(all_items))
```

The latter method would not work if the item IDs were set using strings with spaces, however.

(Also, `tree.get_children()` returns a tuple, so the conversion to list in the original code could also be removed and it would work. In my full code, I was generating the list in a more complicated way, though).